# mutate_at is not applied to all columns selected

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to subtract one column from all others but not all columns are modified.

```
test <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 2:4, c = 3:5, d = 4:6, e = 5:7)

col = 'd'
test %>% mutate_at(vars(-a), funs(. - !!as.name(col)))

      a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    -2    -1     0     5
2     2    -2    -1     0     6
3     3    -2    -1     0     7
```

I am not sure why the function isn't applied to column e.
Function seems to be applied only up to the column I am using to subtract

```
col = 'b'
test %>% mutate_at(vars(-a), funs(. - !!as.name(col)))

  a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     0     3     4     5
2     2     0     4     5     6
3     3     0     5     6     7
```

I get the same behaviour when I use 'list' instead of 'funs' (although i haven't managed to figure out how to use dynamic variable name in 'list')

```
test %>% mutate_at(vars(-a), list(~. - b))
  a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     0     3     4     5
2     2     0     4     5     6
3     3     0     5     6     7
```

Let me know if I am doing anythiing wrong here.

Comment: Check on `dplyr`'s GitHub, but I believe `_at` processes variables sequentially, so this is expected behavior, your best bet is creating new columns with inserting a name in `list`, but in future I believe they will also 'fix' this by introducing alternatives to `_at` (`across` I believe)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense because the columns are subtracted sequentially. That means you get d = d-d, so d = 0, then e-d = e. You essentially overwrote d, so its subtracting 0 from subsequent columns.

Comment: Tyvm @AndS.  This is extremely clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to pull the values you want first, then apply the subtraction.

```
library(tidyverse)

col = 'd'
vals <- pull(test, {{col}})

test %>% mutate_at(vars(-a), list(~.-vals))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       a     b     c     d     e
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1    -2    -1     0     1
#> 2     2    -2    -1     0     1
#> 3     3    -2    -1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col = 'd'
test %>%
    mutate(temp = !!as.name(col)) %>%
    mutate_all(funs(. - temp)) %>%
    select(-temp)
```

Comment: tyvm for the suggestion.  i thought it looked gd initially but it leaves column d unchanged instead of 0